C++: Operator= Overlaoding Gives Error "function operator= does not match"
Straight to the point, the operator = overloading gives an error even both sides of = are of the same type.
main.cpp
ItemType data;
DoublyIterator<ItemType> itor(m_List);
data = itor.Next(); // this line gives the error of the below pic


ItemType.hpp
ItemType& operator=(ItemType& data)
{
    this->SetName(data.GetName());
    this->SetId(data.GetId());
    this->SetManufacturer(data.GetManufacturer());
    return *this;
}

DoublyIterator.hpp
template <typename T>
T DoublyIterator<T>::Next() {
    m_pCurPointer = m_pCurPointer->next;
    return m_pCurPointer->data; // data is also of the generic template which gives ItemType in main.cpp
}


I cannot find what is wrong with the code although there must be. Looking for new perspectives that might catch the error in the code.

[Updated: Minimal Reproducible Code] - Updated to have const qualifiers
The new error was asked in a different question due to this one being closed for duplicate
The old error is gone after const qualifying,
but a new error (which is a good thing?) occurs when trying to setName of ItemType due to "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=[address])"
main.cpp
#include "DoublySortedLinkedList.h"

int main() {
    DoublySortedLinkedList<ItemType> m_List;
}

ItemType.h
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ItemType {
public:
    ItemType(int Id) {
        m_Id = Id;
        m_sName = "";
    }

    int GetId() const {
        return m_Id;
    }

    string GetName() const
    {
        return m_sName;
    }

    void SetName(const string &inName) {
        m_sName = inName;
    }

    void SetId(int inId) {
        m_Id = inId;
    }

    ItemType& operator=(ItemType const &data) {
        this->SetName(data.GetName());
        this->SetId(data.GetId());
        return *this;
    }
protected:
    int m_Id;
    string m_sName; 
};

DoublyIterator.h
#include "DoublySortedLinkedList.h"

template<typename T>
struct DoublyNodeType;
template<typename T>
class DoublySortedLinkedList;

template <typename T>
class DoublyIterator
{
    friend class DoublySortedLinkedList<T>;
public:
    DoublyIterator(const DoublySortedLinkedList<T>& list) : m_List(list), m_pCurPointer(list.m_pFirst) {};
    T Next();
private:
    const DoublySortedLinkedList<T>& m_List;
    DoublyNodeType<T>* m_pCurPointer;
};

template <typename T>
T DoublyIterator<T>::Next() {
    m_pCurPointer = m_pCurPointer->next;
    return m_pCurPointer->data;
}

DoublySortedLinkedList.h
#include "ItemType.h"
#include "DoublyIterator.h"

# define min ItemType(INT_MIN)
#define max ItemType(INT_MAX)

template<typename T>
class DoublyIterator;

template <typename T>
struct DoublyNodeType
{
    T data;
    DoublyNodeType* prev;
    DoublyNodeType* next;
};

template <typename T>
class DoublySortedLinkedList
{
    friend class DoublyIterator<T>;
public:
    DoublySortedLinkedList();
private:
    DoublyNodeType<T>* m_pFirst;
    DoublyNodeType<T>* m_pLast;
    int m_nLength;
};

template <typename T>
DoublySortedLinkedList<T>::DoublySortedLinkedList() {
    m_pFirst->data = min; // header // this is where the new error occurs when debugging
    m_pLast->data = max; // trailer // probably this will cause the error
    m_nLength = 0;
}


Why is data mutable in ItemType& operator=(ItemType& data) ? Please show a [mre]. I also suspect that you've forgotten to make GetName(), GetId() and GetManufacturer() const qualified.

ItemType& operator=(ItemType& data) should be ItemType& operator=(ItemType const& data)  in order to accept temporary objects

Recommendation: provide a [mre] rather than snippets. It wasn't necessary to get you an answer this time, but they're very helpful to future askers with similar problems.
